# How to rerequest permission once denied by user

Tags: ios, security, permissions

Users can post messages on Facebook using my application. iOS presents the users with the permission dialogue the first time they try to post ("foo app would like to post privately on your behalf" - Don't Allow / OK). Now it seems that this decision is a persisting one. Once this dialogue is completed either way, the user will never be asked again.

Now, as this might have happened out of mistake I don't think this is good enough for the user. Is there a way to initiate this permission dialogue from code somehow?

Comment: Even if I remove the app from the simulator, and run it again from Xcode, the permission dialogue is not shown again. It's only redisplayed if I delete my facebook account and recreate it

Comment: Ok, I think I know the answer. The user can access the given application under Privacy/Facebook. If they denied access the application will be listed as "Off" and they can switch it on (which is equivalent of granting access).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can create your own dialog telling the user that they must go to the Settings app to change the privacy settings.

Comment: Yes, if you examine whether the access to the given account has been granted or not. What I didn't understand was what exactly happens if a user denies or accepts the permission request. Now I know that your app is listed under the given account (Facebook or Twitter etc) and it has a on/off switch which tells you if you have granted access for that app or not.

Comment: We had a similar issue with fetching current geolocation after someone denied the permission.  The solution was to handle the error callback when calling `getCurrentPosition` and check if `error.code === PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED` ([docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#PositionError)), showing an appropriate error message per this answer.